# Technical reasons for using HTML5 doctype, instead of 4.01 strict

Tags: html

I'm working on a new website, and I want to support as many old browsers and operating systems as possible, as easily as possible. From what I've been reading, I know I'm better off avoiding quirks mode, so I need to decide on the best doctype. And everyone seems to be recommending the HTML5 version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

But according to this website, that also recommends the HTML5 version:
https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/, that doctype will trigger quirks mode in Netscape 6, and maybe in Konqueror 3.2. But this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

won't trigger quirks mode in any browser listed on that website.

So my question is, is there any reason why I shouldn't use the 2nd doctype? I know those are really old browsers I'm concerned about, but I've seen recent statistics saying Netscape 6 is still in use, at least in Russia. And where I live, I still see a lot of people using Windows XP. So while I don't want to spend a lot of time supporting obsolete browsers, I'm wondering if there are any disadvantages to using the 2nd one, other than it's longer and looks complicated.

edit: All the answers and comments posted so far, have been really helpful. Now I'm starting to see that it's a tradeoff between:
1) being semantically correct, and
2) putting more of the very old browsers into standards mode, instead of quirks mode

In most cases #1 is probably more important, since not many people use those really old browsers. And if they do, they're probably used to things looking a little off. But if you're more concerned about things looking better in really old browsers, then #2 could be a better choice.

Anyway, I'll wait a while to see if anyone adds any more answers or comments. Thanks!

edit 2: All 3 answers were helpful. And 2 of them helped me understand specifically what I needed, so I selected one of those. But I would have selected both, if I could have.

Comment: Did you ever use Netscape 6? It was a truly awful browser. If there is anybody still using it, they're not doing so because they desire perfect page layouts.

Comment: I was using Netscape in the late 90's, so I probably did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is that if you want or need to use HTML 5 in the future you'll be able to with more ease already doing everything in HTML 5.

And browsers should have no problem dealing with the fact that it's strict 4.01 and will display it just as if it didn't have the doctype anyways.

Basically from a "what the page looks like" point of view your strict 4.01 will look the same in a html 5 doctype as it will in a strict.

**Having said that, it does depend on your HTML there are certain times that you'll need to do it but chances are it shouldn't matter**

Really good link for further info on doctype declarations:
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/markup/the-doctype-tag-and-its-effect-on-page-rendering.html#fbid=JCm-bKCUNc6

Comment: This might be a dumb question (I haven't worked a lot with browsers), but do browsers that support some HTML5 elements, allow those elements, if you're using a 4.01 doctype? If they don't, then that's the part I wasn't understanding. If they just ignore the 4.01 part of the doctype, then I still don't get it:)

Comment: I'm actually not entirely sure, I mean it should but I could be wrong.

Comment: I know the video tag works with chrome, beyond that I make no guarantees. As long as the browser knows what the tag is it shouldn't have a problem, doctypes are useful in setting out the rules but browsers don't really need them.

Comment: I guess it could be a semantic problem to use HTML5 elements with a 4.01 doctype. Maybe that's why everyone recommends using the new doctype? I was only thinking about display problems, with older browsers.

Comment: It more or less is to be honest. it shouldn't have any meaningful impact on user experience/simpler webpages.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons:

- Old browsers(those that doesnt support html5) wont be forever, one day the will be gone but those browsers that can support html5 will take long time in order to be a "old browser". So try to take advantages of all those new html5 feactures.
- HTML5 has some new tags that are better for S.E.O
- HTML5 Introduced new video codecs that will improve the audio and video experience.
- HTML5 introduced a really drag and drop feature!

So what I suggest you is to use html5 and try do your best to make "old browsers" run your html5 website.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the , but not use any HTML 5 specific features, I think that would work nicely. Older browsers try to render the page as good as they can. In any case, if you DO want to use HTML 5 features, you can always see if they are available in your javascript code or use a framework such as modernizr.

Comment: I also don't want to require javascript, at least for basic functioning. So I don't think I can rely on feature detection.

Comment: I very much like that approach, just make sure you don't use HTML 5 features and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to me main reason is that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Html5  : Supports header, footer and section tag. And this tags are easily readable to google for "Search Engine Optimization". So, google takes it as important content on our page.

And for "4.01 strict" :
These header, footer and section tags are not supported.

Comment: I understand that some new tags were added in HTML5, and they weren't available in 4.01. But I've been reading about how browsers actually use doctype's, and they seem to ignore them for everything except to decide whether to use quirks, standard, or almost standard mode. And I don't think they reject new HTML5 tags, even if you tell them you're using 4.01.  But I could be wrong about that, which is part of the reason I posted the question.